# Call a function expression with args within render() - react native

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native, expression, render

So I read [this article](https://codeburst.io/6-simple-ways-to-speed-up-your-react-native-app-d5b775ab3f16) about 6 ways on how to speed up your react native app by Atinder Singh.

TLDR;
 "Bind early and don’t create functions inside render.
Do this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.doWork = this.doWork.bind(this);
  }
doWork() {
    // doing some work here.
    // this.props.dispatch....
  }

  render() {
    return <Text onPress={this.doWork}>Do Some Work</Text>
  }

}
```

NOT

```
<Text onPress={ () => this.doWork() }>Do Some Work</Text>
```

OR

```
<Text onPress={ this.doWork.bind(this) }>Do Some Work</Text>
```

Because render is called very often and every time you do any of the two things above, a new function is created." - Oct/13/2017

In my environment the function `this.doWork` get's invoked with with every render. So I changed it to `const doWork = () => {...}`
Works fine. But how do I call the fct with arguments? When I do `this.doWork(x, y)`, the fct again get's called with every render.

Is there an effective way on how to call this fct without technically creating a new one with every render?
Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: what do u mean by ` new function is created `?

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. Is there an effective way on how to call this fct without technically creating a new one with every render?**
>
> **2. But how do I call the fct with arguments?**,

You can use **[`function currying`](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html)**

```
doWork = (param) =>(e)=>{

    console.log('Event', param);
};
```

inside render:

```
 render(){
         return <Text onPress={this.doWork('someHardValOrProp')}>Do Some Work</Text>
    }
```

Working **[`React#codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqypw83vny)** example.